# Memory addressing general form confusion

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The memory addressing general form (found it [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/rhel-doc/OldFiles/3/rhel-as-en-3/i386-memory.html)) is:

```
[base + index*scale + disp]
```

So a correct instruction would be something like:

```
mov eax, [ebx + ecx*4 + 2]
```

---

And this instruction should be incorrect (but NASM found it to be correct!):

```
mov eax, [ebx + ecx + 123 + 5 - 2]
```

So why is this instruction correct (even though it does not conform to the memory addressing general form)?

I think it is correct because:

- `123 + 5 - 2` are all considered to be one number (`126`) representing `disp`.
- The documentation says: *"If no scale is specified, scale is taken to be 1"* (so `ecx` is effectively: `ecx*1`).
- So the final result is: `mov eax, [ebx + ecx*1 + 126]`.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Assemblers can fold assembly-time constants for you, so things like `123 + 5 - 2` are collapsed. All of the parts that you see in the "general form" are optional except for one.

Comment: Note that even something like `mov eax, [ebx - 2 + ecx + foo]` is correct—`foo` is treated as a symbol name and a relocation for `foo - 2` is emitted.

Comment: @fuz You mean `disp` can be a variable (for example `section .data foo DB 12`)? What about `scale`, can it also be a variable?

Comment: No! In that case `disp` would be the _address_ of the variable and _not the value_ of it. To put it another way: if disp=eax then it'd be `mov eax, offset disp` and not `mov eax, dword [disp].

Comment: @user8240761 Yes, `disp` can be a variable, but note that its address, not its value will be used.

Comment: @fuz What about `scale`, can it also be a variable (the address of the variable that is)?

Comment: @fuz Can `scale` also be a variable (the address of the variable that is)?

Comment: @user8240761 I don't think so. Since scale can only be one of 1, 2, 4, or 8, that wouldn't make much sense.